# How to configure bokeh plot to have responsive width and fixed height

Tags: python, bokeh

I use bokeh embedded via the components function.

Acutally I use :

```
plot.sizing_mode = "scale_width"
```

Which scales according to the width and maintains the aspect ratio. But I would like to have a responsive width but a fixed or maximum height. How is that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are `stretch_both` and `scale_both` options.

> How the item being displayed should size itself. Possible values are "fixed", "scale_width", "scale_height", "scale_both", and "stretch_both".
>
> "stretch_both" elements are completely responsive (independently in width and height) and will resize to occupy all available space, even if this changes the aspect ratio of the element. This is sometimes called outside-in, and is a typical behavior for desktop applications.
>
> ...
>
> "scale_both" elements will responsively resize to for both the width and height available, while maintaining the original aspect ratio.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html

Comment: So maybe the answer to the question is. Something like. Use Strech both and limit available height in css... where i embedd the plot?

Comment: Yeah I think that's the ticket. I did that and it has worked so far. Plz consider accepting the answer if it works for you!

Comment: Could you provide an example? I have tried the following- p=figure(x_axis_type='datetime', width=1000, height=300, sizing_mode="scale_both")   I have also tried setting this outside as in p.plot.sizing_mode="scale_both"    I am really unclear about how and where to set this properly.

Comment: -update--**** I got it figured out-     p=figure(x_axis_type='datetime', width=1000, height=300) /n  p.sizing_mode="scale_both"

Answer (score 2):

You manually set the height and width for the two plots, and set sizing_mode='scale_width' for the layout/gridplot, as follows (this will set a fixed aspect ratio and allow you to scale by width):

```
    plot1 = figure(width=1000, height=300)
    # add lines here

    plot2 = figure(width=1000, height=100)
    # add lines here

    plots = gridplot([[plot1], [plot2]], sizing_mode='scale_width')
    show(plots)
```

Comment: Yea, but that does not answer the question... Responsive width, fixed height.